# Tensorflow dense_image_warp Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using up-to-date Keras and Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04. For the following code:

```
img2D = Input(shape=(100, 100, 3))
refPosX = Input(shape=(100, 100, 1))
refPosY = Input(shape=(100, 100, 1))
# refImg = Input(shape=(100, 100, 3))

# Passing values to depth net
depth_map = depth_net(dFeatures)
curX = tf.multiply(depth_map, refPosX)
# curY = K.dot(depth_map, refPosY)
curY = tf.multiply(depth_map, refPosY)
# dMove = concatenate([curX, curY])
dMove = tf.concat([curX, curY], axis=3)

warped = tfc.image.dense_image_warp(img2D, dMove)
```

I'm receiving the error output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/carson/ws/dla/test_network_5/depth_and_color_nets.py", line 89, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/dense_image_warp.py", line 195, in dense_image_warp
    [batch_size, height * width, 2])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6482, in reshape
"Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 513, in _apply_op_helper
raise err
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 10000, 2]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I'm a bit confused as I don't know where I'm going wrong here. Why would the elements not be of a supported type? At what point am I passing a list object to the function?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, you must define input as

```
Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, h, w, c))
```

The function requires batch_size. which you can generally get away without when using Keras.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the shape of the inputs. The function `tfc.image.dense_image_warp` requires inputs of shapes `[batch, height, width, channels]` and `[batch, height, width, 2]` respectively with a specified batch size. (cf https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/dense_image_warp)

Specifically, `None` values for batch size are not supported and lead to the error you have encountered.